# Efficient way of counting large numbers it items in set, in Python?

Tags: python, count, permutation, large-data, memory-efficient

So, I have this code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.7

from itertools import permutations

count = len(set(permutations(range(171476), 3)))

print(f'Final Count: {count}\n')
```

However, I'm really trying to get the final count in a more efficient manner, but I don't know of the library function I'm looking for or a different way of getting the answer in a more efficient manner.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Took your suggestion khelwood, thank you

Answer (score 2):

You are creating 3-permutations of the integers `[0, 171476)`. This means that in the result tuple the first integer has `171476` options, the second `171476 - 1` choices and the last one `171476 - 2`. Notice the pattern?

```
def num_permutations(n, k):
    result = 1
    while k:
        result *= n
        k -= 1
        n -= 1
    return result
```

With that we find our answer:

```
>>> num_permutations(171476, 3)
5041995277625400
```

Comment: I think this is my intention, I'm trying to get all the permutations of that number in groups of three, so (0,0,0), (0,0,1), (0,0,2), etc...

Comment: @GregTheHun That's a different function... `permutations` does not allow re-use of elements. If you allow the same number to be used multiple times it's just `n**k`. The function you describe is [**`itertools.product`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

Comment: Right, the goal would be to get as big of a list of groupings of three items in a list (that is very large), I wouldn't want the order of the three items to be exactly the same, but you could have the three same words in a different order.

Comment: It seems the itertools.product function is the best case of what I'm looking for. However, now I wonder if there's a good way to count the item a little faster using multiprocessing. Maybe even using collections.Counter? (Edited original post)

Comment: @GregTheHun Please undo your edits and post a new question instead.